# Notepad++ RexEx Remove everything between 2 html tags ( with line break between )

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I want to remove in a html document with notepad++

everything between the marked area 
[image]
So the Start point to remove is ( including ) `"<imgCRLF"` and then everything between including CRLF
and then including `"DetailsCRLF</aCRLF"` for the End ponint

I started simple with `<img.*<a/>` and ticked [image]

and I tried to improve this starting point but always got either nothing was deleted or to much :)

Comment: `.*` grabs as much as possible, what happens if you change it into `.*?` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<img.*?</a>[\r\n]*`. The `.*` is too greedy. `[\r\n]*` will capture the whitespace after `</a>`.

[image]

Also, if you are only interested in matching `<img` with subsequent line breaks, you can use another regex:

```
<img[\r\n].*?</a>[\r\n]*
```

Comment: This doesn't only capture the ones with line breaks in the `<img` tag though... (At least, that is my interpretation on OPs requirement)

Comment: Good point, I added a regex example that will cover that situation, too.